# Drawing a polygon with x and y axis using Java FX

Tags: java, javafx, graph, polygon, stage

I am trying to draw a polygon with an x and y axis using Java FX. I've spent 12 hours searching online with no luck!!! :(

[image: I want to draw using Java FX something like this]

Polygon

```
import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.scene.Group; 
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon; 
import javafx.stage.Stage;  

public class PolygonExample extends Application { 
   @Override 
   public void start(Stage stage) {        
      //Creating a Polygon 
      Polygon polygon = new Polygon();  

      //Adding coordinates to the polygon 
      polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{ 
         300.0, 50.0, 
         450.0, 150.0, 
         300.0, 250.0, 
         150.0, 150.0, 
      }); 

      //Creating a Group object  
      Group root = new Group(polygon); 

      //Creating a scene object 
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300);  

      //Setting title to the Stage 
      stage.setTitle("Drawing a Polygon"); 

      //Adding scene to the stage 
      stage.setScene(scene); 

      //Displaying the contents of the stage 
      stage.show(); 
   } 
   public static void main(String args[]){ 
      launch(args); 
   } 
}
```

I have this but it doesn't have the axis!!

Comment: I am confused, do you want to display the axis on the window, or learn how to display a specific polygon? I think you should edit the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a polygon by replacing your `polygon.getPoints().addAll()` statement with..

```java
//Adding coordinates to the polygon 
polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{ 
      100.0, 250.0,
      200.0, 100.0,
      400.0, 100.0,
      500.0, 250.0,
});
```

Your points were off for some reason, that's all.

Try to think of how you would draw this by hand. I just picked the leftmost point and added points in the order I would've used if I had drawn the thing by hand on a piece of paper.

**Displayed by this code:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, by the axis I mean the x and.y axis showing the coordinates of the points. Do you think there is any way I could do this?

Comment: The top left point is (0, 0). The further right you go, the higher the x value becomes. The lower you go, the higher the y value becomes. You define the maximum x and y values when you create the Scene object. Unfortunately, I am not sure if JavaFX has a way to show the axis itself.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using the "JavaFX Chart Extensions" package by Emxsys.

Download the `jfxchartext-1.1.zip` library from
https://bitbucket.org/emxsys/javafx-chart-extensions/downloads/

It contains the jar file `jfxchartext-1.1.jar` which you can include in your project.

You can then use one of their enhanced charts - like the `EnhancedScatterChart`.
You can add an `XYPolygonAnnotation` with the polygon coordinates as shown in the example code (see link below - scroll down to the section **Polygon Annotations**.

https://bitbucket.org/emxsys/javafx-chart-extensions/wiki/XYAnnotation%20Extension

For the point coordinates you can use `XYTextAnnotation` - see the bottom of the page.